# anonymous array of objects parsed to list<object-with-matching-variable-names>

Tags: c#, arrays, api, json.net, anonymous-types

This is the value that I get returned from the api. my current code says this should be a jsonarray to deserialize correctly.

I believe this is an anonymous array with a list (or array) of objects.
I have tried the following
I am using c# and newtonsoft JSON

Question:
how do I get the objects out of this anonymous array and put into a list??

the variable 'dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata' is the model that has the parameters required by api

```
A Failed:
var test = new { typeof(dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata) };

dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata Token_Metadata = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType<dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata>(jString, test);


B Failed:
var test = new[] { new dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata() };

dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata Token_Metadata = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType<dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata>(jString, test);


C Failed:
dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata Token_Metadata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<new[] {new dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata()}>(jString);



D Failed:
dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata[] Token_Metadata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata[]>(jString);



E Failed:
List<dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata> Token_Metadata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata>>(jString);


F Failed:
var test = new { dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata };

dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata Token_Metadata = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType<dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata>(jString, test);



G Failed:
var test = new{ Address = "", name = "", symbol = "", decimals = "", logo = "", logo_hash = "", thumbnail = "", block_number = "", validated = "", created_at = ""};

dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata Token_Metadata = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType<test>(jString, test);
```

The 'jString' variable contains the anonymous array string of objects that i received from the api call.

```
[
  {
    "address": "0x95ad61b0a150d79219dcf64e1e6cc01f0b64c4ce",
    "name": "SHIBA INU",
    "symbol": "SHIB",
    "decimals": "18",
    "logo": "https://cdn.moralis.io/eth/0x95ad61b0a150d79219dcf64e1e6cc01f0b64c4ce.png",
    "logo_hash": "0dba9c0d492b42b3a73c5ceee62b205568a8b5c1932cac048ccd71cbbe051690",
    "thumbnail": "https://cdn.moralis.io/eth/0x95ad61b0a150d79219dcf64e1e6cc01f0b64c4ce_thumb.png",
    "block_number": null,
    "validated": null,
    "created_at": "2022-01-20T10:39:55.818Z"
  },
  {
    "address": "0xbb0e17ef65f82ab018d8edd776e8dd940327b28b",
    "name": "Axie Infinity Shard",
    "symbol": "AXS",
    "decimals": "18",
    "logo": null,
    "logo_hash": null,
    "thumbnail": null,
    "block_number": "12314534",
    "validated": 1,
    "created_at": "2022-01-20T10:39:55.818Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: E looks correct. Please show the definition for  `dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata`. There is nothing anonymous about a JSON array, it's just an array, and `JsonConvert` can put it into either a C# array or `List<T>`

Comment: Can you show dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata too pls?

Answer (score -1):

you can create anonymos object at first and after this to deserialize, but this looks much more readable for me

```
var result = JArray.Parse(json)
    .Select(jo => new
    {
        address = jo["address"],
        name = jo["name"],
        symbol = jo["symbol"],
        decimals = jo["decimals"],
        logo = jo["logo"],
        logo_hash = jo["logo_hash"],
        thumbnail = jo["thumbnail"],
        block_number = jo["block_number"],
        validated = jo["validated"],
        created_at = (DateTime?) jo["created_at"]
    }).ToList();
```

or if you like to do it hard way , by using DeserializeAnonymousType

```
var definition = new[] { new  {
        address = "",
        name = "",
        symbol = "",
        decimals = "",
        logo = "",
        logo_hash = "",
        thumbnail = "",
        block_number = (int?)null,
        validated = "",
        created_at = DateTime.Now
    }};

var result =JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, definition ).ToList();
```

or you have to post dmReturn_Token_BaseMetadata to see if it or a part of it fits as a definition. In this case it can be used as a definition.